# Why is my treeview flat?

Tags: vba, recursion, treeview

I have built a tree structure from my data set. Now I'm trying to represent that hierarchy in a TreeView, using the following code.

First, create all the root notes:

```
For Each nodeObject In NodeCollection
    If nodeObject.rank = 0 Then
        treeUCD.Nodes.Add key:=nodeObject.Name, Text:=nodeObject.Description
    End If
Next nodeObject
```

Then, iterate over each level of the hierarchy and add one level of children at a time:

```
For i = 1 To treeHeight
    For Each nodeObject In NodeCollection
        If nodeObject.rank = i Then
            treeUCD.Nodes.Add nodeObject.Parent.Name, tvwChild, _ 
                nodeObject.Name, nodeObject.Description
        End If
    Next nodeObject
Next I
```

But every node is created as a root node. How do I assign children?

**EDIT:**
There is a problem with how I assign rank to the nodes. My recursive function returns 0 every time, although stepping through reveals that it is incrementing properly:

```
Function GetRank(nodeObject As clsNode, ByRef rank As Integer)
    If nodeObject.Parent Is Nothing Then
        GetRank = rank
        Exit Function
    End If
    GetRank nodeObject.Parent, rank + 1
End Function
```

**EDIT**
The iterative function is now working:

```
GetRank = GetRank(nodeObject.Parent, rank + 1)
```

but the treeView is not displaying any children.

Comment: It's a TreeNodeCollection - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Then this is not exactly a `vba` related question?

Comment: @Vityata How is it not vba-related?

Comment: @Tomalak - 2 optons: Option 1 - It is using an external .NET library and it is a VB.NET. Then it is not a VBA. 2. It is using an external .NET library to VBA. Then it is a VBA.

Comment: I see no .NET anywhere in this question. What makes you think of .NET?

Comment: @Tomalak - The comment of the OP?

Comment: Ahhh, didn't notice that link. OP needs to clarify.

Comment: It's Access VBA.

Comment: But the link in your first comment goes to .NET documentation. .NET VB and VBA are *completely* different.

Comment: This is the VBA documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733703(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the TreeView was working, but root nodes don't display a + icon next to them - you have to double-click to expose its children!

Comment: That's a setting you can change on the TreeView control.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function does not return a value in the `Else` case. This is better:

```
Function GetRank(nodeObject As clsNode, rank As Integer) As Integer
    If nodeObject.Parent Is Nothing Then
        GetRank = rank
    Else
        GetRank = GetRank(nodeObject.Parent, rank + 1)
    End If
End Function
```

But actually I suggest a non-recursive variant here, it's more straight-forward:

```
Function GetRank(nodeObject As clsNode) As Integer
    While Not nodeObject.Parent Is Nothing
        GetRank = GetRank + 1
        Set nodeObject = nodeObject.Parent
    Wend
End Function
```

Your tree-building is also not optimal. Instead of going over the nodes repeatedly, create them in the same fashion your input tree is organized.

```
Sub CreateNodes(tv As TreeView, myNode As clsNode, Optional tvRefNode As node)
  Dim childNode As clsNode

  For Each childNode In myNode.Children
      CreateNodes tv, childNode, tv.nodes.Add( _
          Relative:=IIf(tvRefNode Is Nothing, vbNull, tvRefNode.Index), _
          Relation:=tvwChild, _
          Key:=myNode.Name, _
          Text:=myNode.Description _
      )
  Next childNode
End Sub
```

All you need to do now is pass your root node as a starting point.

```
CreateNodes myTreeView, myRootNode
```